# How to make sticky navigation bar only for horizontal scrolling?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a huge table that goes out of screen and I have horizontal and vertical scroll. Now, my problem is that I want to make sticky navbar which stays on top only on horizontal scroll and hides when I scroll down... and again shows when I scroll on top of page.

I tried this solution with css and js, but navbar hides also when I scoll horizontally. It should be hidden only on vertical scroll

```
    <style>
        #sticky {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
        window.onscroll = function() {
            var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
            if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
                document.getElementById("sticky").style.top = "0";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("sticky").style.top = "-70px";
            }
            prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `overflow-x: scroll` to have horizontal scroll bar:

```
#sticky {
      height: 60px;
      display: table-row;
      background: #333;
      position: fixed;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Sure, you can add style via JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('sticky').style.overflowX = 'scroll';
```

Comment: Is there any way to do that with JavaScript? I have updated my question

Answer (score -1):

You have to use position sticky which works like a toggle between fixed and relative based on your scroll position

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width:200vw;
  height:300vh;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100vw;
  left: 0;
  position: sticky;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div id="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```